# EPPlus AddPicture renders a black box for the image in the file

Tags: c#, image, epplus

I am using this code to insert an image from a URL into an excel file, but it renders as a black box in the file.

```
string url = Regex.Match(row[column.ColumnName].ToString(), "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
var pic = worksheet.Drawings.AddPicture(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ImageUtilities.GetImageFromUrl(url, Request));
pic.SetSize(400,200);
pic.SetPosition(rowIndex, 0, columnIndex, 0);
```

I have verified the image coming back from the server is valid (I have saved it to the filesystem and opened it) Here is the code to fetch the image.

```
 public static Image GetImageFromUrl(string url, HttpRequestBase request) {
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

            if (request != null) {
                httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                // add auth cookie and session cookie so graphs/etc will render correctly
                if (request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null) {
                    var oldCookie = request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
                    var cookie = new Cookie(oldCookie.Name,oldCookie.Value, oldCookie.Path,"localhost");
                    httpWebRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
                }

                if (request.Cookies[PROVIDERPORTALSESSION_COOKIE] != null) {
                    var oldCookie = request.Cookies[PROVIDERPORTALSESSION_COOKIE];
                    var cookie = new Cookie(oldCookie.Name, oldCookie.Value, oldCookie.Path, "localhost");
                    httpWebRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
                }
            }

            using (HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse()) {
                using (Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream()) {
                    var image= Image.FromStream(stream);
                    return image;
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Is it still black if you don't set the size?

Comment: Yes. I have tried both ways.

Comment: Does this happen to a specific set of images or all images?

Comment: They are all similar. They are images of people's signatures taken on a mobile device

Comment: If you import a random image from the internet do you get the same issue?

Comment: Also, what file format are the images from the mobile device? e.g. jpg Which version of excel is the document you're importing the images into created with?

Comment: @Jamleck An image from the web is working fine. The signature is in PNG format. EPPlus is creating a new document, not an existing one.